# How does Windowproc go back to my GetMessage() loop?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have been following a tutorial for directx programming, and It starts off with learning how to program a window.

So far I have this and it creates a blank window:

```
#if       _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0500
  #undef  _WIN32_WINNT
  #define _WIN32_WINNT   0x0500
#endif

#define _UNICODE
#define UNICODE

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd,
                            UINT message,
                            WPARAM wParam,
                            LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow){

    HWND hWnd;

    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass1";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                          L"WindowCLass1",
                          L"Window Program",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          300,
                          300,
                          500,
                          400,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    //ShowWindow( GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE );

    MSG msg;

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);

        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd,
                            UINT message,
                            WPARAM wParam,
                            LPARAM lParam)
                            {
                                switch(message)
                                {
                                case WM_DESTROY:
                                    {
                                        //ShowWindow( GetConsoleWindow(), SW_RESTORE );
                                        PostQuitMessage(0);
                                        return 0;
                                    }break;

                                }
                                return DefWindowProc  (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
                            }
```

So far I understand it, up until the getmessage loop.  I know that it receives a windows msg and translates it to a readable one and sends it to be processed by the window proc function.  But, I don't understand how the window proc function doesn't end the program, and how after entering on input the program doesn't simply close.  If code is executed from top to bottom, and the winmain ends before the windowproc, why is a command processed by windowproc to the be all and end all and it returns to the getmessage?

Comment: _"If code is executed from top to bottom, and the winmain ends before the windowproc (...)"_ - `winmain` doesn't end before `windowproc`.

Comment: But doesn't the curly brace ends before the windowproc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your message loop calls `DispatchMessage`.  That calls your window procedure.  Then your window procedure returns, `DispatchMessage` also returns, and your loop loops.

Well, that's how posted messages work.  For messages sent from other threads, it's `GetMessage` (or a handful of other wait functions that don't appear in your code, but might be used during default message handling) that calls the window procedure.  It actually has a loop of its own, calling window procedures until it finds a posted message.  Then it returns so you can inspect the message and call `DispatchMessage`.

Also, a lot of different window procedures can be called by `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage`, depending on to which window the message was sent or posted.  Your window procedure gets called for windows associated with the window class you registered, so basically all messages sent to your main window.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  In that case, what line's telling windowproc to return back to the DispatchMessage?

Comment: The line that says `return` :)  Actually, you have two of them, one `return 0;` and one `return DefWindowProc(stuff);`

Comment: `SendMessage` bypasses the message loop altogether and directly calls into the window procedure. Sent messages are only dispatched by `GetMessage`/`PeekMessage` when they cross threads.

Comment: @IInspectable: True, and I've clarified, but that also happens inside the context of the message loop (except for the initial `CreateWindow` call).  The main thread spends all of its time in the message loop.

Comment: That's still not accurate: `SendMessage`/`PeekMessage` service **all** sent cross thread messages before moving on. As always, extensive information can be found at Raymond Chen's blog: [When can a thread receive window messages?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/08/150929.aspx)